# Simple Bray-Curtis Dissimilarity Matrix Help: Vegan

Tags: r, vegan

I am trying to create a Bray-Curtis dissimilarity matrix with this data to investigate community change from a 2017 sampling year to a 2019 sampling year based on catch per unit effort (CPUE). 2017 and 2019 will be treated as different "sites" so I can calculate compositional dissimilarity between the two.

I am most interested in how this relates to native fish vs. nonnative fish in each life-stage (adult and juvenile). And honestly, I have no idea where to even start. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is the data

```
         Species Year Age_Class       CPUE
1    Native Fish 2017  Juvenile 0.01538462
2    Native Fish 2017     Adult 0.01538462
3    Native Fish 2019  Juvenile 1.16492147
4    Native Fish 2019     Adult 0.01832461
5 Nonnative Fish 2017  Juvenile 0.63846154
6 Nonnative Fish 2017     Adult 0.54102564
7 Nonnative Fish 2019  Juvenile 0.47905759
8 Nonnative Fish 2019     Adult 0.60209424
```

Data in dput() format

```
structure(list(Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 2L), .Label = c("Native Fish", "Nonnative Fish"), class = "factor"), 
                      Year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2019L, 2019L, 2017L, 2017L, 2019L, 
                                2019L), Age_Class = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                1L), .Label = c("Adult", "Juvenile"), class = "factor"), 
                       CPUE = c(0.015384615, 0.015384615, 1.164921466, 0.018324607, 
                               0.638461538, 0.541025641, 0.479057592, 0.602094241)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                          -8L))
```

Comment: Please provide the data in `dput()` format. Copy and paste the output of `dput(data)` here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but here I have reshaped your data to have each of the combinations of `species` and `age_class` treated as your "Species" variables, and years as "sites". So you are only getting a single distance value returned; namely, the dissimilarity between 2017 & 2019:

```
library(vegan)
library(reshape2)
df <- structure(list(Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
  2L, 2L), .Label = c("Native Fish", "Nonnative Fish"), class = "factor"), 
  Year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2019L, 2019L, 2017L, 2017L, 2019L, 
  2019L), Age_Class = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
  1L), .Label = c("Adult", "Juvenile"), class = "factor"), 
  CPUE = c(0.015384615, 0.015384615, 1.164921466, 0.018324607, 
  0.638461538, 0.541025641, 0.479057592, 0.602094241)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                          -8L))
df$code <- paste(gsub(pattern = " ", replacement = "_", x = df$Species), 
  df$Age_Class, sep = ".")
df2 <- dcast(data = df, formula = Year ~ code, fun.aggregate = sum, 
  value.var = "CPUE")
df2
#   Year Native_Fish.Adult Native_Fish.Juvenile Nonnative_Fish.Adult Nonnative_Fish.Juvenile
# 1 2017        0.01538462           0.01538462            0.5410256               0.6384615
# 2 2019        0.01832461           1.16492147            0.6020942               0.4790576
dim(df2)

D <- vegdist(x = df2, method = "bray")
D
#             1
# 2 0.000834997
```

Comment: Hi Marc. This is fantastic thank you. From here, how would I go about creating a Dissimilarity Matrix to help in running a PERMANOVA? Obviously the native juvenile fish is where we see that large change in composition from 2017 to 2019 and that single distance number does not captured that. My end goal is to run a PERMANOVA with a CAP Visualization, with each species that comprises the "native fish" and "nonnative fish".